# Interval of existence of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation
$$\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y^2 \sqrt x, y(1) = 1$$
has the solution 
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x(2-\sqrt x)}$$

I have trouble finding the existence interval for it.

I think it is 
$$ 0 < x <4$$
$$ 4< x <\inf $$

but the book gives only the interval 
$$ 0 < x <4$$

Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ must be contained in the domain of existence, as your solution must satisfy the condition $y(1)=1$. And once you are in $1$, you cannot escape $(0,4)$

Comment: @boon heT Thank you. Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Happens to everyone :) glad to be of help